# Fix boot partition & boot loader for Fedora 39

Tags: fedora, boot, grub, uefi

I ran `dnf upgrade --refresh` nd it told me that there's not enough room on my /boot partition to apply it so I pulled up a guide with Google to extend the /boot partition which went something like (I unfortunately don't have the link handy):

1. Create new boot partition
2. mount existing boot partition
3. copy files from existing to new
4. Adjust `grub.cfg` (?)
5. reboot

and trns out that after rebooting, my Fedora system doesn't boot anymore but I still can boot into Windows.
When I choose my Fedora 39 system in the bootloader, I just get to a screen that shows me:

```
Generating "/run/initramfs/rdsoreport.txt"

Entering emergency mode. Exit the shell to continue.
Type "journalctl" to view system logs.
You might want to save "/run/initramfs/rdsoreport.txt" to a USB stick or/boot
after mounting them and attach it to a bug report.

Press Enter for maintenance
(or press Control-D to continue):
```

When I boot from the Fedora 39 stick, I see the following partition layout:

```
Device               Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1        2048     206847     204800   100M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2      206848     239615      32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3      239616    1837055    1597440   780M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p4     1837056  212959231  211122176 100.7G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p5   212959232  215056383    2097152     1G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p6   215056384 1953318911 1738262528 828.9G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p99 1953318912 1953523711     204800   100M Linux filesystem
```

Where I see two problems:

1. /dev/nvme0n1p99 should be of type EFI System
2. /dev/nvme0n1p99 should be larger than 100M (I could swear that I tried to create a 200MB partition)

How do I restore my system to be able to boot into Fedora again? Optimally I would also be able to double the size of the EFI partition to 200M, let's say and then boot from that.

The disk in the KDE Partition Manager looks like this:
[image]

Mind that I've erased the /dev/nvme0n1p99 partition and tried to reduce the size of `/dev/nvme0n1p6` to make more room art the end but for some reason, it keeps snapping back to 828.87GB).

So my initial goal is to just be able to boot into my system again, I will deal with the size of the partition at another point!

Comment: Do not confuse an ESP - efi system partition which must be FAT32 with boot flag and only one per drive for most systems with a /boot partition which must be Linux format.